# SAPUI5: Add new "ViewSettingsItem" in into ViewSettingsDialog in a Fragment

Tags: javascript, fragment, sapui5

Currently I have a fragment for sorting purpose. When user click on sorting button. 
It display following screen.

[image]

However, what I need to to is I have to add "ViewSettingsItem" dynamically into
"ViewSettingsDialog" in Fragment. I have no idea how to achieve it because for fragment.xml. We do not have controller. Where should we add the new “ViewSettingsItem” dynamically?

The following is my sample code for fragmen.xml

```
<core:FragmentDefinition id="customerSortDialogFragment" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m">
    <ViewSettingsDialog confirm="onSortDialogConfirmed" id="sortingViewSettingsDialog">
        <sortItems>
            <ViewSettingsItem id="idCUSTOMER_ID" key="CUSTOMER_ID" selected="true" text="Customer ID"/>
            <ViewSettingsItem id="idCUSTOMER_NAME" key="CUSTOMER_NAME" text="Customer Name"/>
            <ViewSettingsItem id="idADDRESS_LINE_1" key="ADDRESS_LINE_1" text="Address Line 1"/>
            <ViewSettingsItem id="idADDRESS_LINE_2" key="ADDRESS_LINE_2" text="Address Line 2"/>
            <ViewSettingsItem id="idPRIVATE_NUMBER" key="PRIVATE_NUMBER" text="Private Number"/>
        </sortItems>
    </ViewSettingsDialog>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if a fragment doesn't have a controller, you see the `confirm="onSortDialogConfirmed"`, that method needs to be implemented somewhere, right? Well that is done in the controller of the view where you are calling the fragment.

In the same controller, you can get the `ViewSettingsDialog` instance and manipulate just like any other control.

[Check this sample](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.17/preview) of opening a dialog fragment and [it's code here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.tutorial.walkthrough.17/code).

In your scenario you can try the following in the controller method that opens the fragment, (referring to the sample link above)

```
//Get the dialog instance
var oDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "path.of.your.fragment", this);
// connect dialog to view (models, lifecycle)
this.getView().addDependent(oDialog);
//Create a Sort Item and add it to the dialog
var oCustomSortItem = new sap.m.ViewSettingsItem({text:"New settings item"})
oDialog.addSortItem(oCustomSortItem);
oDialog.open();
```

[ViewSettingsDialog documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ViewSettingsDialog)

[ViewSettingsItem documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ViewSettingsItem)